# jQuery Catcomplete with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So, I'm trying to use HTML links in my catcomplete results, but jquery automatically transforms my html code into text, like on the image:

[image: jQuery CatComplete]

And my jQuery code is:

```
$( "#global-search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    source: "globalsearch.php"
});
```

Please, dont say to me to use `select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        }`, because it works only once when using ajax (I really don't know why, but it just doesn't work), and I asked some questions here yesterday asking how to fix it, and nobody helped me with it.

So, back with the html transformed into text, how can I add an html hyperlink to my results?

globalsearch.php:
[image]

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to fit a round peg in a square hole. Find a plugin which is designed for what you require.

Comment: Would you link to catcomplete documentation? I cannot find it using Google.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Custom Data and Display example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data). You will see that they have replaced the `_renderItem` method with a custom one. You'll need to do the same thing to override how your items are displayed.

```
$('#global-search').data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append((item.link) ? "<a href='" + item.link + "'>" + item.label + "</a>" : "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Without seeing the output of your `globalsearch.php` I can't tell you exactly how to set it up, but basically you'd want to add a `link` attribute to your returned JSON and if the link exists, print the anchor with the link as its `href`.

How you handle the selection links vs outside links is left as an exercise to the OP.

Comment: does it work with `catcomplete`? and I updated the post with an image of globalsearch.php output

Comment: It works with `autocomplete`, so it should work with `catcomplete`. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

From the autocomplete widget documentation

> Independent of the variant you use, the label is always treated as
>   text. If you want the label to be treated as html you can use Scott
>   González' html extension. The demos all focus on different variations
>   of the source option - look for one that matches your use case, and
>   check out the code.

Scott González' html extension is https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js. I have also posted the code below.

```
/*
 * jQuery UI Autocomplete HTML Extension
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Scott González (http://scottgonzalez.com)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 *
 * http://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions
 */
(function( $ ) {

var proto = $.ui.autocomplete.prototype,
    initSource = proto._initSource;

function filter( array, term ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i" );
    return $.grep( array, function(value) {
        return matcher.test( $( "<div>" ).html( value.label || value.value || value ).text() );
    });
}

$.extend( proto, {
    _initSource: function() {
        if ( this.options.html && $.isArray(this.options.source) ) {
            this.source = function( request, response ) {
                response( filter( this.options.source, request.term ) );
            };
        } else {
            initSource.call( this );
        }
    },

    _renderItem: function( ul, item) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( $( "<a></a>" )[ this.options.html ? "html" : "text" ]( item.label ) )
            .appendTo( ul );
    }
});

})( jQuery );
```

EDIT try the code below while using the extension

```
$( "#global-search" ).catcomplete({
    delay: 0,
    html: true,
    source: "globalsearch.php"
});
```

Comment: How do I use it? I tried opening the console, executing and see what happens, nothing changed... Does it work with catcomplete? @_@

Comment: @SergioToledoPiza See my edit at the bottom of my answer. I do not know for sure whether it will work; I am following the documentation.